# Filtering an array by enum

Tags: java, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a table that contains document types, which are specified by enums.

```
@Table(name = "document")
public class  Document extends AbstractPersistable<UUID> {

@Id
private UUID id;

@Column(name = "type")
@Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
private DocumentType type;

}



public enum DocumentType {
    ANNUAL_ACCOUNTS,
    APPENDIX,
    BANK_GUARANTEE,
    BUDGET,
   
}
```

Right now I can access all of the enums by using a filter in Vuejs.

```
computed: {
  filteredDocuments() {
    return (this.documents ?? []).filter(document =>
      document.name.toUpperCase().includes(this.search.toUpperCase()) ||
      this.$t(`model.document.types.${document.type}`).toUpperCase().includes(this.search.toUpperCase())
  }
 }
```

But what if I want to filter by a specific enum? For instance, what if I only want to return a document type that is equal to the enum "APPENDIX"? How would I write this into my filtering method?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra clause to your filter:

```
return (this.documents ?? []).filter(document =>
      (document.name.toUpperCase().includes(this.search.toUpperCase()) ||
      this.$t(`model.document.types.${document.type}`).toUpperCase().includes(this.search.toUpperCase())) &&
      document.type === 1)
```

Instead of using `document.type === 1` it would be nicer to create an enum in your frontend and use something like `document.type === DocumentType.APPENDIX`. This is under the assumption that your backend returns the enum as an integer and not as a string.